# UIView+Autolayout is not giving me the proper positioning - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using the [UIView+Autolayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout) library to make code-based Auto Layout constraint creation easier, but I'm having trouble adding a constraint with this library.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.captionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.captionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Which uses the normal NSLayoutConstraint addition methods, and it works beautifully. But when I try to do something similar with UIView+Autolayout:

```
[self.captionLabel autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisHorizontal];
[self.captionLabel autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:20.0];
```

It comes out aligned in the middle vertically and off to the left side.

What am I doing wrong for setting this up?

Comment: any photos? I would imagine that one possibility to be that it is actually aligned to the superview, just not to the one expected. Is there any logs about Auto Layout not able to satisfy all criteria?

Comment: Even if I explicitly define what the other view is, it still isn't laid out properly. All constraints are satisfied, yes.

Comment: Have you unit test the methods you're using.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, the first line using UIView+AutoLayout tries to mimic the functionality of the second line without, correct? Going back to the source, I find something quite interesting. The method `autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge` calls `al_attributeForAxis`. When you pass the `ALAxisHorizontal` to `al_attributeForAxis`, it actually returns `NSLayoutAttributeCenterY`.

Comment: Have you had success using the autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis on other views? Just for testing purposes; try this category (which is similar, and I have had success using the center-functionality here myself): https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

Comment: nonetheless https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry is better. And all Cons, described in UIView-AutoLayout, not critical.

Answer (score 2):

The code you shared using the NSLayoutConstraint API:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.captionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.captionLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Would translate into the following using the [UIView+AutoLayout API](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout):

```
[self.captionLabel autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:0.0];
[self.captionLabel autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisVertical];
```

Note that `ALAxisVertical` is the correct constant to use, not `ALAxisHorizontal` as you originally had. To understand why, take a look at the [comments where this enum is defined](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout/blob/master/Source/UIView%2BAutoLayout.h#L48-L52):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ALAxis) {
    ALAxisVertical = NSLayoutAttributeCenterX,      // a vertical line through the center of the view
    ALAxisHorizontal = NSLayoutAttributeCenterY,    // a horizontal line through the center of the view
    ALAxisBaseline = NSLayoutAttributeBaseline      // a horizontal line at the text baseline (not applicable to all views)
};
```

If you align the vertical axes of two views, as we are doing here, you end up adjusting their x-position and/or size so that they end up (what you might describe as) centered horizontally. That's likely where some confusion lies. As always, a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Illustration of aligning a view to its superview using ALAxisVertical]

When you understand how the `ALAxis` constants are defined and think about it visually, it makes sense (and you'll see that it is consistent with how these constants get used throughout the API).